# (data-protecting) want to mask/replace some data in database

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g

I'm working on a problem in which i have to mask/replace (i know they are both different)some data like credit card no,account no,date of birth etc with a particular pattern .
for example if a credit card no. is like 123/456/789 it will show ###/###/### in front end .

The solution i thought is to use regexp_replace function and it's working but the problem is that it's taking to much time and the query is very tedious and is giving a new column for each pattern(need to match more than 75 pattern for only credit card no. and account no.)+ future pattern will also come

Secondly,is it possible that we can creating a table in which we can store all the pattern and reflect to that table using dynamic sql query ??(if we get the table create access)(but i don't know how to do this )

Thirdly,we can use procedure to mask the data(not replace the data with a pattern),generate the random no. for protecting of data.(I don't think so they will agree on this ,the senior members).

if any other optimum solution is there please share,i also don't know that all the credit card no,account no etc reside in one table or they are present in more than one table, if the data is present in more than one table then what will be the solution ??

Detailed explanation needed....

Answer (score 0):

From a design point of view these data points should have been stored in unique columns -- a column for credit card numbers for example. Is that not the structure of this table? If it is, why would you even include that column in your query? If cc numbers, etc. are included with other columns you may want to take the time to re-structure if you plan to use moving forward.

Continued on if they are stored in the same column -- you are really risking a breach of PII by relying on a replace function to remove sensitive information. Consider other options for accessing the data you need so that you don't breach confidential information due to a mistake in data entry.